# regex to get information out

Tags: php, regex

I have a string and I want to extract out some information for it.
The string could be like this

```
$string = "Followers: abc.com. ID by: xyz@gmail.com. More info: all the rest of information goes here. All other goes everywhere else."
```

**the $string sometimes just have**

```
$string = "ID by: xyz@gmail.com."
```

**or**

```
$string = "Followers: abc.com."
```

or any other combo. I am just trying to see if there is ID by there and get that out.

What would be the best way to achieve this

Comment: So in the example given, you want a result of `"ID by: xyz@gmail.com."`, or do you just need to know if the ID portion is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression with `preg_match` to find the ID.

```
preg_match('/ID by\\: ([\\w@\\.]+)\\.(?: |$)/',$input,$matches);
```

The ID (email address) will be in `$matches[1]`. The pattern matches "ID by: ", captures the email address, and finally requires a period + space or end of string.